# Stored procedure expects parameter when no IN parameters are defined

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have this very simple stored procedure in Oracle that executes a sequence and gives the next sequence number as output.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE NEXT_NUMBER
(SEQUENCE_OUT OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO sequence_out;
END;
```

As you can see, there are no IN parameters to this procedure so I'm puzzled when I execute this procedure like this: execute CRS_NEXT_CRC_NUMBER;

and I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
execute NEXT_NUMBER
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CRS_NEXT_CRC_NUMBER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Any idea why this could be happening? I can call the NEXTVAL function on the SEQUENCE outside of the procedure without a problem.

Comment: You have not declared the OUT variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE NEXT_NUMBER
(SEQUENCE_OUT OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL INTO sequence_out FROM DUAL;
  -- or simply (in newer Oracle releases)
  sequence_out := TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

In SQLPLUS:

```
> var ID NUMBER
> exec NEXT_NUMBER(:ID);
> print ID
```

Answer (score 1):

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CRS_NEXT_CRC_NUMBER'

You have not declared the OUT parameter and the program expects an argument, i.e. the OUT parameter `SEQUENCE_OUT`.

You could execute the procedure with the OUT parameter in two ways.

- SQL*Plus variable
- Anonymous block

In **SQL*Plus:**

```
var SEQUENCE_OUT number
exec next_number(:SEQUENCE_OUT);
print SEQUENCE_OUT
```

**Anonymous block:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
   SEQUENCE_OUT NUMBER;
BEGIN
   next_number(SEQUENCE_OUT);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SEQUENCE_OUT);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You done almost correct. You need to call method like

```
execute NEXT_NUMBER(:val);
```

You don't set out parameter, which will take out value.